# Retrieve places by type from android maps api

Tags: android, json, google-maps, geolocation

I am using Geocoder from android maps api to retrieve places in android studio. It is working but not how I wanted. I want to search by location address and choose type and get all match results from that address and selected type.

```
String searchString = "London";
Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(searchString, 10);
if (list.size() > 0) {
    Address add = list.get(0);
    String locality = add.getLocality();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Found: " + locality, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Can I instead put for instance London and select location type like "Stadium" and get all stadiums from london?

I have tried another solution but not sure if I can implement it to the Android, which is googleapis that retrieve JSON:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=stadium+Near+London=true

It gives me correct answer but only one results,
I have two questions here:
1. how can I get all match stadiums?
2. Can I implement it in an android app? like reading retrieved json data from the app?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should actually be using the places API for Android instead of the geocoder. The geocoding API isn't really intended for returning multiple results of a certain type, but the place API is. Please see the article on getting place predictions programmatically here:

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically

This will allow you to bias results to a certain area, such as london. And allow you to return results of a certain type, such as stadiums. While this may not be exactly what you are looking for, I believe this is the closest thing Google provides. You may also want to take a look at the other things the Places API for Android can do here:

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start

I hope this helps!

Comment: Appreciate your help, but unfortunately android places api is not as much helpful. It put alot of limitation in terms of number of values requested. I did use place api for web application. It returns values by json and seems to be the most helpful one so far.